# Laravel custom request not found

Tags: php, laravel

I got my custom request RegisterRequest and I'm trying to use it but for some reason I always get this error like i'm not including it:

```
ReflectionException in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 25:
Class App\Http\Controllers\RegisterRequest does not exist
```

this is my request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'emailconfirm' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'passwordconfirm' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages(){
        return [
          'username.required' => 'Username is required',
        ],
    }
}
```

and this is how i'm trying to use it:

```
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
```

and in my method:

```
public function RegisterPost(RegisterRequest $request){

      return response()->json($request->all(),200);
    }
```

I always get 500 internal server error with message that request does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command may help:

```
composer dump-autoload
```